# Get excel to display a number in a cell as it is written

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column of values, the first of these is 5780250200001450

In the cell, it appears as 5.78025E+15

But I want it to appear as the number at the top (which is what appears in the edit text box when I click the cell).

I have tried formatting the cell to be 'text' but it makes no difference, it still appears with E+15 in the cell and correctly in the edit textbox when I click the cell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force Excel to treat numbers as text:

1. Highlight the column
2. Choose `Data`->`Text To Columns`
3. Choose `Next` (Delimited default is fine)
4. Choose `Next` (Tab default is fine)
5. Set "`Column data format`" to `Text`
6. Choose `Finish`

This will re-import the column on top of itself as text (without having to prepend everything with `'` )

Answer (score 1):

You have to format it as a number.  Same screen as Format as Text, only choose Number from the Category list.

If you don't want to format it as a number then you have to precede numeric values with a `'` (apostrophe character), which will force Excel to treat the value as text.

Comment: I want it to be treated as text as some of the records contain letters as well as numbers (and these appear correctly as General)

Comment: @SLC Formatting the number shouldn't change how it is read by other cells, just how it looks in the cell

Comment: @SLC see my edit